# I can't get my JavaScript collisions to work. How should you check for them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, physics

I have been working on a small physics game in JS where you use a block to move other blocks and they collide.  My collisions sometimes stop working, and I do not know why.  I'm also not sure if I'm checking for them the correct way.

```
this.checkCollision = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) ||
        (mytop > otherbottom) ||
        (myright < otherleft) ||
        (myleft > otherright)) {
        crash = false;
    }
    if (crash) {
        this.colliding = true;
        $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
        this.collide(otherobj);
        // this.x++;
    } else {
        $('body').css('background-color', 'white');
        this.colliding = false;
    }
    return crash;
}
this.collide = function(otherobj) {
    //for when they stick
    if (this.speedX < 0.1 && this.speedY < 0.1) {
        this.x -= 2;
        otherobj.x += 2;
    }
    //get speed of x
    otherobj.speedX = this.speedX;
    this.speedX = -((this.mass * this.speedX) + (otherobj.mass * otherobj.speedX)) / (this.mass + otherobj.mass);
    // get speed of y
    otherobj.speedY = this.speedY;
    this.speedY = -((this.mass * this.speedY) + (otherobj.mass * otherobj.speedY)) / (this.mass + otherobj.mass);
}
```

[Fiddle is Here](https://jsfiddle.net/knoxkeaton/hqpsb3n0/8/)

Comment: In your JSFiddle, if you set `blueGamePiece.speedX = -5;` it will move it to the left, which makes it collide properly with the red block. Is what you want for them to move in opposite directions when they collide?

Comment: Are you sure your collision logic is right? Wouldn't a 'collision' be when either your myTop or myBottom are between other bottom and other top, and also myLeft or myRight are between otherLeft and otherRight... no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your collision detection code seems to work in the example given if you set `blueGamePiece.speedX = -5`. If your goal is to make the two bodies exchange velocities when they collide, the following will help:

```js
this.collide = function (otherobj) {
    // swap X speeds
    temp = otherobj.speedX;
    otherobj.speedX = this.speedX;
    this.speedX = temp;
    // swap Y speeds
    temp = otherobj.speedY;
    otherobj.speedY = this.speedY;
    this.speedY = temp;
}
```

This simply swaps the velocities without negating (notice the temporary `temp` variables), which causes the collisions to work fine, and for the objects to move in opposite directions. If you want  to use proper momentum, you can try to adjust the code to use the relevant formulae.